# Create an optional tuple

Tags: c++, boost, tuples, variadic-templates, option-type

I don't understand why there is no `optional tuple`, and I mean by that, something like this ; `optional<int,string,char>` that would combine an `optional int`, `optional string` and `optional char`.

You can think of it like an optimized `std::tuple<boost::optional<T>...>`

where the `booleans` used by the `optionals` would be all together at the end of the `structure` in order to pack it, or even better, be stored in a bitset.

That may reduce the memory of the structure A LOT, and also is more elegant :

`std::tuple<boost::optional<int>,boost::optional<string>,boost::optional<char>>`

**VS**

`optional<int,string,char>`

I can think of a way of doing this, using the implementaion of `boost::optional` and `variadic templates`, but before starting this, I would like to know if this is a good idea, what would be a better way of implementing this, what are the difficulties I would be facing ?

**EDIT :**

Basically why I don't like `std::tuple<boost::optional<T>...>;`

Since an `optional<T>` is a union of `T` and a `bool` :

[image]

The new structure can save a lot of memory !!

Comment: I know you're talking about the boost optional, but the C++17 "vocabulary" types are still being designed. You should submit a proposal to the C++ committee if you think std::optional could use that

Comment: Also, maybe you could define your own "optional" template alias coupled with a factory function for declaring and constructing your variadic optional.

Comment: @KABoissonneault I was thinking of something like that, but I am not sure there won't be any issues with the `optional`like `move`'ing data

Comment: Excellent illustration. Yes this has been discussed more often around. As to "why does this not exist" I don't think the question is well -suited. But +1 for the question in case someone comes along with a viable implementation

Comment: @sehe Thank you, I wanted actually to try an implementation using boost::optional, since I thought it is a simple `T` and `bool` structure, but when I saw the boost implementation I realised it may need a lot of work to make it as good as `std::tuple<boost::optional<T>...>` with less memory. Seems I will have to go for it anyway

Comment: An optional tuple is **not** the same as a tuple of optionals ! Your proposition amounts to writing a specialization for `std::tuple<optional<Ts>...>`, but this is simply an optimization, and probably not useful enough to have been proposed for inclusion. Keep in mind that `std::optional` is due for C++17, so the current standards don't even know about it yet.

Comment: @AlexandreC.  "An optional tuple is not the same as a tuple of optionals" , everybody agrees on that, "Your proposition amounts to writing a specialization for `std::tuple<optional<Ts>...>`" Not a specialisation, something that would work as `std::tuple<optional<Ts>...>` but with less memory

Comment: @AlexandreC. : We've seen what happened with the `std::vector<bool>` specialization. That wasn't pretty, even though a bitvector is quite useful. I really think `std::tuple<X,Y,Z>` should contain members of type X,Y and Z even if X happens to be `optional<int>`.

Comment: `optional<T>` is not the union of a `bool` and a `T`. You can consider it the (discriminated) union of a `T` and an empty type (e.g. `struct {};`). 'Discriminated' meaning that there has to be a discriminator in the implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may implement yourself, something similar to:

```
/**
 *  Similar to `optional`, but take the bool as argument.
 */
template <typename T>
class out_optional
{
public:
    out_optional() {}

    out_optional(const out_optional&) = delete;
    out_optional& operator =(const out_optional&) = delete;

    void destruct(bool b) { if (b) { reset(b); } }

    void reset(bool& b) { if (b) { reinterpret_cast<T*>(data)->~T(); b = false; } }
    void reset(bool& b, const T& value) { reset(b); new (data) T{value}; b = true; }
    void reset(bool& b, T&& value) { reset(b); new (data) T{value}; b = true; }

    const T* get_ptr(bool b) const { return b ? reinterpret_cast<T*>(data) : nullptr; }
    T* get_ptr(bool b) { return b ? reinterpret_cast<T*>(data) : nullptr; }

    const T& get(bool b) const { assert(b); return *get_ptr(b); }
    T& get(bool b) { assert(b); return *get_ptr(b); }

    // Other stuff as swap, pseudo assignment/move, more constructors

private:
    alignas(T) char data[sizeof(T)];
};

/**
 * 'Tuple' of optional, packaged with bool at the end.
 */
template <typename ... Ts>
struct multi_optional
{
    template <std::size_t I>
    using type = typename std::tuple_element<I, std::tuple<Ts...>>::type;

    static_assert(std::is_same<int, type<0>>::value, "");
public:
    multi_optional() = default;

    ~multi_optional()
    {
        destruct(std::index_sequence_for<Ts...>());
    }

    multi_optional(const multi_optional&) = delete; // To be implemented.
    multi_optional& operator =(const multi_optional&) = delete; // To be implemented.

    template <std::size_t I>
    const auto* get_ptr() const { return std::get<I>(data).get_ptr(flags[I]); }

    template <std::size_t I>
    auto* get_ptr() { return std::get<I>(data).get_ptr(flags[I]); }

    template <std::size_t I>
    const auto& get() const { return std::get<I>(data).get(flags[I]); }

    template <std::size_t I>
    auto& get() { return std::get<I>(data).get(flags[I]); }

    template <std::size_t I>
    void reset() { return std::get<I>(data).reset(flags[I]); }

    template <std::size_t I>
    void reset(const type<I>& value) { return std::get<I>(data).reset(flags[I], value); }


   // Other stuff as copy/move assignment/constructor, ...

private:
    template <std::size_t ... Is>
    void destruct(std::index_sequence<Is...>)
    {
        int dummy[] = { 0, (std::get<Is>(data).destruct(flags[Is]), 0)... };
        static_cast<void>(dummy);
    }

private:
    std::tuple<out_optional<Ts>...> data;
    std::array<bool, sizeof...(Ts)> flags = {{}};
};
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/eubXB0)

Comment: Thank you for the implementation, that's a nice work. But I still want to know if using this would be a lot more efficient than a `std::tuple<boost::optional<T>...>;`  ?? (regardless the gained memory)

Comment: @OthmanBenchekroun: As you explain in your schema, you gain some padding space (Order for `Ts` is also important in this regard). You can also replace my `array<bool, N>` by a more compact structure (`std::bitset`). For efficiency, as the `bool` is no longer near of its `data`, it is less cache friendly (now it depends also of number of type in `multi_optional`).

Comment: ok I see, I will try to do some tests using your implementation

Comment: @Jarod42: "less cache friendly" ? I'm not so sure. If the `bool` is `false`, there's no data to be near to.

Comment: @MSalters: I think it might be a problem in extreme case (*lot* of `Ts`), but should be ignored in most case.

Answer (score 0):

Is it not a good option to use a template alias?

```
template <typename... T> using optuple = 
    boost::optional<std::tuple<T...> >;
```

Or, in fact the other variation if you preferred;

```
template <typename... T> using optuple = 
    std::tuple<boost::optional<T>...>;
```

Now you can just write

```
optuple<std::string, double, int> x;
```

and get the meaning you chose.

Of course, if only one of the tuple members is ever filled, this already exists: `boost::variant<T...>`

Comment: Thank you for the answer, however as I explained I don't really want to use `std::tuple<boost::optional<T>...>;`  The structure has a lot of padding due to the `boolean`'s between data

Comment: @sehe also not one of members only is filled, they may be all filled

Comment: Ah. I suppose you could pack it indeed (like `using optuple = std::tuple<std::bitset<sizeof...(T)>, std::tuple<T...> >;` but then with proper lazy in-place construction and logic.). That's more work yes.

Answer (score 0):

The structure you want can already be created as a specialization of `tuple<T>`. There's no purpose in introducing an additional structure. There's nothing different here compared to making a special `vector` just to employ EBO.

What you want is covered perfectly well by the existing interfaces. If you desire another *implementation*, you could always specialize I guess or roll your own.

Comment: I think (assuming `std::optional` is already there) that partially specializing for `template <typename... Ts> class std::tuple<std::optional<Ts>...>` would be illegal. By the usual rules that specializations in the std namespace need to be for user-defined types?